# Default JOIN in BusinessObject Universe (version 4.1.)

Tags: business-objects

Is "INNER JOIN" the default join in a BusinessObject univese? If not, which one is? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, unless you specify outer join (left, right or full, depending on which checkboxes you tick in the join properties), inner join is the default join using in both UNV and UNX universes.

Comment: Thx! OK - to sum up: INNER JOIN is the default join. Additionally, I know how to make RIGHT and LEFT JOIN. However, I do not know how to make FULL JOIN, since I can't click on both checkmarks assigned to two tables, when I on "Edit Join" click. Therefore, please tell me how u define FULL JOIN. Thx!

Comment: if you're going to define a full outer join, make sure you have the ANSI92 parameter on universe level turned on. See the section _Outer Joins_ in chapter 3 of the [Universe Designer User Guide](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir31SP3/en/xi31_sp3_designer_en.pdf) for more information (there's a paragraph on full outer joins as wel).

Comment: Where can I turn the ANSI92 parameter on?

Comment: Again, have a look at the documentation I linked to, page 174 describes the parameter.

Comment: The documentation you are referring to is for the old UDT. However I am using IDT 4.1. The "old" documentation says I should click to File-> Parameters. However, when I click on File, Parameters are not shown. Additionally, in the new documentation I did not find the description about setting this parameter. May I ask you for the instruction on how to do it?

Comment: Have a look at the [Information Design Tool User Guide](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbo41/en/sbo41sp3_info_design_tool_en.pdf). This is described in section 10.18.2 _Setting SQL generation parameters in the data foundation_ (page 182). The parameter itself is described in section 18.4.1 _SQL generation parameters reference_ (page 433).